# How to match html tag.id or tag.class names using adblockparser rules?

Tags: python, web-scraping, adblock

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')
for tag in soup.find_all(True):
    print rules.should_block([TAG ID OR TAG CLASS])
```

As I know Adblock can block HTML element based on its names.

For example:

If a `div`'s ID is `#ads` it would be blocked.

How can I do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block a class name, you will need the filter

```
||domain.com##.classnamehere
```

To block an element by ID, you will need the filter

```
||domain.com###IDnamehere
```

If you're trying to understand filters better, there's a good primer here: https://adblockplus.org/filters

If you're trying to understand which filters are affecting a particular site, there's a good filter search-engine here: http://blockadblock.com/search-adblock-filters.php

Adding the filters to a Python parser is probably beyond the scope of this answer but there's plenty of good documentation here: https://github.com/scrapinghub/adblockparser

Comment: Thanks, This is if I know the domain name. but what if I want to detect ads with its ID and Classes names.
I have file HTML page -> bs4 -> Adblockparser -> detected blocks

Comment: Note that you cannot use `||` when specifying domains for element hiding filters.